# AWS Step function string/json concatenation

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I have orchestrated a data pipe line using AWS Step function.
In last state I want to send a custom notification. I'm using an Intrinsic function States.Format to format my message and subject. It works fine for Context object element. Here, I have tested that in Message parameter.
But it doesn't work with input JSON. This is my input JSON
**{
"job-param":{
"pipe-line-name":"My pipe line name", "other-keys":"other values"
}
}**

```
 "Success State": {
  "Type": "Task",     
  "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::sns:publish",
  "Parameters": {    

  "Message.$": "States.Format('Execution Id:{}, completed successfully!', $$.Execution.Id)",
  "Subject.$": "States.Format('[INFO] {} completed successfully!', $.job-param.pipe-line-name)",

  "TopicArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:************:sns-topic"
  },
  "End": true
}
```

While saving this state machine, it gives me following error message:

> The value for the field 'Subject.$' must be a valid JSON Path

I checked Input and Result path. They have this value. I can directly use this value as parameter. This is working fine. But I can't format with other string.

```
"Subject.$": "$.job-param.pipe-line-name"
```

Alternate approach would be to call lambda to customize and trigger SNS. But I want to avoid that.

Can I request some suggestions to fix this error?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Change your input JSON and replace `-` with `_`:
```
"Subject.$": "States.Format('[INFO] {} completed successfully!', $.job_param.pipe_line_name)",
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to use any name with `-` in your JSON then you can write your JSON Path like this:

```
"Subject.$": "States.Format('[INFO] {} completed successfully!', $['job-param']['pipe-line-name'])",
```

But it would be easier if you change your input JSON and replace `-` with `_`:

```
"Subject.$": "States.Format('[INFO] {} completed successfully!', $.job_param.pipe_line_name)",
```

Comment: Thanks Poorya, converting - to _ was not possible as in my case. But $['job-param']['pipe-line-name'] worked as expected.